# How implement 2^x++ in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Hi i programing function in Haskell, that convert binary number to decimal

i have function remainder

```
--return last bit
portion :: Integer -> Integer 
portion10 n = n `div` 10

remainder10 :: Integer -> Integer
remaindern10 n = n `mod` 10
```

now i wanna binToDec with use recursive

```
binToDec 0 = 0
binToDec binary = (remainder10 binary) * 2^x++ + binToDec (portion10 binary)
```

i need know how i can implement 2^x++ in me binToDec function :/ please help :)

Comment: What does that mean? What's `2^x++`?

Comment: by algorithm to convert binary number to decimal number indexing number from right  ... 2^0 2^1 2^2 ...*0 || *1

Answer (score 2):

First off, you can't change variables in Haskell. Pretty much eveything is immutable. If you want a counter, the simplest way to get one is to add another argument to a function:

```
binToDec binary = binToDec binary 0 where
  binToDec' 0 _ = 0
  binToDec' binary counter = (remainder10 binary) * 2^counter + binToDec' (portion10 binary) (counter+1)
```

Secondly, however, you can actually do rather better in this case. Note that calculating `2^n` requires squaring 2 several times, and doing some extra multiplications. You can actually do without that.

Answer (score 1):

Or without explicit recursion, with just playing with list functions

```
import Data.List
import Data.Tuple

binToDec x = sum $ zipWith (*) (unfoldr remainder x)
                               (iterate (*2) 1) where
    remainder 0 = Nothing
    remainder x = Just . swap  $ divMod x 10
```

`iterate (*2) 1` is the answer to your question , how to "implement `2^x++`".

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it like this, just another version:

```
binToDec :: Int -> Int -> Int
binToDec 0 _ = 0
binToDec b c = mod b 10 * 2^c + binToDec (div b 10) (c + 1)
```